# <node.js> How can I efficiently parse a flat array of values into an object with nested attributes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, object

So I'm hooking into an application api that returns a flat array of values - the order of the values defines the specific structure of data, and I'd like to be able to transform this array into an object that reflects this underlying structure.

Working backward, this is what I'd like to end up with:

```
{"app_name":"app_X",
 "affected_nodes" : [
                       {"node_name":"node_X","node_id":"xxx"},
                       {"node_name":"node_Y","node_id":"yyy"}
                    ]
}
```

But this is what I'm given:

```
["app_X","2","node_X","xxx","node_Y","yyy"]
```

The actual data is much more complex, with multiple tiers of attribute arrays nested within each other. As you can see, I'm given the length of each nested attribute in the original flat array, represented in my example as `"2"`. I've started wrangling with transforming the flat array into a proper object structure and the whole business seems very inefficient and difficult to maintain. My approach currently looks something like this:

```
var arr = ["app_X","2","node_X","xxx","node_Y","yyy"];
var obj = {};

obj.app_name = arr[0];

var num_nodes = arr[1];

obj.affected_nodes = [];

var position = 1;

for(var i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++){
    var sub_obj = {};
    sub_obj.node_name = arr[position + 1];
    sub_obj.node_id = arr[position + 2];
    obj.affected_nodes.push(sub_obj);
    position = position + 2;
}
```

This is working, but I feel like there may be a more efficient solution out there that hasn't occurred to me. Is there a better algorithm or perhaps library function to accomplish this sort of task?

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that says that your for loop counter must start at zero or increment by 1 after each iteration. So we can make things simpler by removing that ugly `position` variable:

```
for (var i = 2, length = arr.length; i < length; i += 2) {
    obj.affected_nodes.push({
        node_name: arr[i],
        node_id: (arr[i + 1] || null)
    });   
}
```

Also, I don't know how your `num_nodes` limit can work if `arr[1]` is a string and not an integer.

Comment: Yes I like this approach - I think I could work out a parameterized version where I could pass some descriptors such as position of parents in the array, and the number of child attributes for each particular parent. The api gives arrays of different structure for different event types, and I don't want to have to code in a switch statement to parse the different structures I might receive.